# CSS CDN: Is there some public css files I can use (link to)

Tags: css, cdn

For personal/demo/work in progress, I don't want to make my own css file, but still apply some nice looking standard layout. Is there some public css I can link to? Similar to jQuery CDN links?

I want to do this in my header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://someone.com/styles/xyz/layout.css" type="text/css" />
```

and then possibly one or two wrappers div's in my html file (e.g. `<div class="header">...</div><div class="content">...</div>` )

I looked at jQuery UI Templates, but they were a bit too complex. They require me to set class names to every button, input, check box etc.

Thanks,
Ola

Comment: I've wondered this to- Open, generic styles that work to prettyify most any page. A simple one is adding a box-shadow to all images wider and taller than 100px, it makes every page with images look better.

Comment: I might make one you can just include easily.. I've been wanting one for a while for quick improvement of all sites.

Answer (score 1):

[Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) is a popular CSS starting point at the moment